# Update screen size when in fullscreen and using mobile keyboard

Tags: javascript, android, css, keyboard

That's quite a mouthful! I'm testing some things regarding web apps, so my test page goes fullscreen using `webkitRequestFullscreen`

I then decided to test how an `<input type="text" />` would affect the fullscreen-ness. Sure enough the keyboard comes up just fine, but the content of the page is hidden behind it... including the input field the user would be typing in. Typing blind isn't fun.

I'm trying to figure out the screen size after the keyboard takes some of the space, so that I can adjust the page in such a way that the field becomes visible. However, properties like `screen.height`, `window.innerWidth` and the like all show full-screen values (360x640) regardless of the keyboard being present or not.

Are there any other ways of getting the screen size, while in fullscreen, and factoring in the virtual keyboard's presence?

Here's a demo, try in Chrome on mobile: [link](https://fiddle.jshell.net/qy6rb5hd/1/show/light/)

Comment: On which element (relative to the input) are you requesting the fullScreen ?

Comment: @Kaiido `document.documentElement.webkitRequestFullscreen()` - the whole thing.